# About Polkadot's API List

Tags: polkadot, api, json-rpc

The polkadot.js documentation has a list of APIs on it, but is there any other list of APIs?
The polkadot.js API list includes eth, which cannot be executed without Frontier.
Is there an API List that can be run on just a node with no other packages?

Best regard!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of another list. However, the [documentation](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/) of polkadot js covers such API's which you can use to experiment with the [substrate node template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) (e.g. [cookbook](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/blocks)/[examples](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise)). Try to obtain the latest block, the metadata or balance changes for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  
I'm having a hard time figuring out if the data is multiple or types (string, int, etc) in the polkadot.js documentation.  
Is there any documentation or other documentation that shows this?  
Should I try to run it or check with the execution results?

Answer (score 0):

Substrate is a modular blockchain framework underneath Polkadot.

Users are given the flexibility to create and modify their Substrate based chain however they want, which means that there will not really ever be an offline list of APIs available for all chains.

Instead, the Polkadot / Substrate ecosystem relies on Metadata, which you can learn more about here: https://docs.substrate.io/build/application-development/#metadata-system

By querying the metadata of a chain, you can learn about all its APIs and features, and this is the only way to get the data you are looking for in a consistent way.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' https://rpc.polkadot.io -d '{"id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"rpc_methods","params":[""]}'
```

But no more detail on this result. Such as the rpc's params.

And a further reading related to these things: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/5902